# Closed form of the sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-n^3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, exponential-sum

I am trying to calculate the sum of the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-n^3)$$

Can it be expressed in terms of known mathematical functions?

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know what to do with it. It does converge extremely quickly, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, such expression is not known in the world of commonly used special functions. Its closest analog is the sum $\sum\nolimits_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-n^2}$, which is already quite nontrivial: it is expressed in terms of elliptic [theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

One way to convince yourself that the sum is "too exotic" is to consider a generalization $$f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n^3}.$$
This series converges inside the unit circle $|z|=1$ but the circle itself is a [*natural boundary*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalBoundary.html) of $f(z)$ - that is, a dense set of singularities across which the function cannot be analytically continued. This is to be contrasted with "normal" special functions which usually have a finite or countable number of isolated singular points in the complex plane.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the answer ("it is hard") have been given.

The numerical computation gives

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\mathrm e}^{-n^3}=1.368\dots$

I want to add that a natural first order approximation given by the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums), is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\mathrm e}^{-n^a}\approx\frac{1}{2}+\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)\approx 1.5-\frac{\gamma}{a},$$

where $\gamma=0.577\dots$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

The approximation is best at about $a\approx 4.5$.
For you with $a=3$ we find

$\frac{1}{2}+\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)=1.392\dots$